# scrapping the web with selenium, an error

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to use selenium to get data from the page of tipranks:
https://www.tipranks.com/experts/analysts/dan-payne

the code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.tipranks.com/experts/analysts/john-pitzer'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)

elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_CLASS,"override")

# This is text from the inspector: <text class="override  fontSizemedium colorgreen fontWeightsemibold" x="50%" y="50%" fill="#1ead00" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.28em">69%</text>

for all in elements:
    print(all.text)
```

But it's getting empty results.
I have checked with an inspector the div of the element e.g. **Success Rate** but still the same.

Similarly it doesn't work with XPATH if I make in inspector copy-XPATH as

```
#elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/svg/g/text")
```

Please help me assess what I am doing wrongly, thank you.

Comment: What exact text you wanted ??

Comment: Scraping is spelled s-c-r-a-p-i-n-g

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the text then you can use this XPath

```
//*[contains(@class,'override')]
```

and if you want 69% text then you can use this

```
//*[contains(@class,'override') and contains(text(),'69')]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I am reading on XPATH, hence still got struggle with getting all Company Names and Price Targets with this. What would be XPATH for it? Thank you

Comment: Thank you @iamsankalp89, I have also tried the following: 

`data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//*[@class=”rt-tr-group”]/*[local-name()='g']/*[local-name()='text']")`



to search by class, and get the data as Company, Date, Position, Action,...but it doesn’t give results at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need the Success Rate percentage from that page, for that try this code:

If 'Cookie Privacy Statement' dialog appears, use the below 2 lines of code to handle it:

```
accept_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#cookies_accept_btn")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept_btn)
```

To print the values from the table:

```
total_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,".//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr']")

for row in range( len(total_rows)):
    print("Company:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//a").text, end = "-")
    print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span").text, end = " | ")
    print("Date:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "((.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span)[2]").text, end = " | ")
    print("Position:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"((.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span)[3]").text, end = " | ")
    print("Action:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"((.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span)[4]").text, end = " | ")
    print("Price Target:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"(.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//div[@class='flexccc     displayflex colorpale']").text, end = " | ")
    print("No. of Ratings:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "((.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span)[5]").text, end=" | ")
    print("Success Rate:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@class='flexrsc     displayflex h_pxsmall45 w_pxsmall45'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='g']/*[local-name()='text']").text, end=" | ")
    print("Avg. Return:", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "((.//*[@class='rt-tbody  fontWeightnormal']//div[@class='rt-tr'])[" + str(row + 1) + "]//span)[7]").text, end=" | ")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. That fragment with Cookie Privacy Statement is great and works perfectly. I am still struggling to get Company Names and Price Targets, as those blocks are separate. What would be the XPATH formula for it? Thank you.